# how to enable trace in android 4.3 as in android 4.2

Tags: android, android-debug, systrace

In android 4.2, go to the Settings->Developer options->Enable trace, I can enable the traces and show them in the systrace output chart. But in android 4.3, the enable trace option is removed, so how can I enable traces?

Comment: If all else fails, use the command line tool.  Example here: http://bigflake.com/systrace/

Answer (score 1):

From the [Official Doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#Testing).

> Systrace events for apps
>
> Android 4.3 adds the Trace class with two static methods,
>   beginSection() and endSection(), which allow you to define blocks of
>   code to include with the systrace report. By creating sections of
>   traceable code in your app, the systrace logs provide you a much more
>   detailed analysis of where slowdown occurs within your app.
>
> For information about using the Systrace tool, read Analyzing Display
>   and Performance with Systrace.

Comment: I've read about this. But i want to enable the system traces(like some traces in activitythread.handlermessage) rather than my own traces. In android 4.2 I can enable system trace dynamically. is there any way to do the same in android 4.3?

Comment: Ye Ling Aung - thanks for that info; those technical details are not shown on http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use latest eclipse in [adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729.zip](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), you can find the systrace options like Android 4.2 in the DDMS perspective window in eclipse.

Just like the image in this [blog.](http://www.cppblog.com/wythern/archive/2013/09/09/203109.html)